# Dynamic array can update to larger size for all data types except strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, deep-copy

I designed a dynamic array with an update function that deep copies the contents of the original into a temp array, then doubles the size then puts the contents of temp array into the new one.

This is the function:

```
T& operator[](const unsigned i)
{
    if(i >= SIZE)
    {
         T *temp = new T[SIZE];
         for(int i = 0; i< SIZE; ++i)
         {
             temp[i]=data[i];
         }
         delete[] data;

         SIZE *= 2;

         data = new T[SIZE];
         for(int j = 0; j< SIZE; ++j)
         {
             data[j]=temp[j];
         }
         delete[] temp;
    }
    return data[i];
};
```

This function works with all data types except strings like:

```
Vector<string> s;
string str1 = "1";
string str2 = "2";
s[0] = str1;
s[1] = str2;
cout<< s[0]<< s[1]<< '\n';
```

However with ints for example:

```
Vector<int> in;
for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    in[i] = i;
}
for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    cout<< "int test"<< '\n';
    cout<< in[i]<< '\n';
}
```

The update works perfectly fine.

anyone of you know why?

Thank you.

Comment: It only coincidentally works for non-strings. Rather than solve this issue for you, I will point you to a good debugging tool. Teach a programmer to fish, and all that. Try running your program under *Valgrind*, a program for debugging memory issues. It should show you your error right away, and you will have learned how to use a little bit about a very valuable tool for helping you debug in the future. Good luck, and have fun!

Comment: The second loop copies twice the number of elements from `temp` than it holds.   That is undefined behaviour for any type.   It just so happens that it seems to work for `int` but not for `string` - undefined behaviour is like that (one permitted behaviour is "seems to work sometimes").